# representing a point inside a cylinder using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to plot a point `{x1,y1,z1}` inside a cylinder having end points as `A = {x,y,z}` and `B = {x',y',z'}` and having radius `r`, using Mathematica? An example will be appreciated
**with a diagram**

Comment: Can you clarify the question, in particular what you mean by "represent"?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `Point` and `Cylinder`?

Comment: @SZabolcs  Yeah ,but i am unable to plot both point and cylinder at a time.

Comment: Please be sure to always include int he question what you have already tried. It shows that you do care about getting a solution and it'll bring quicker and better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something similar to

```
Graphics3D[
 {{PointSize[0.03], Point[{0, 0, 0}]},
  {Opacity[0.5], Cylinder[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 0.5]}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]